# Patent marketplace

Tags: traded, resale

I would like to buy patents related to oil and gas drilling and production activities. Is there a market where patents are bought sold or traded? A secondary market? I’ve found several that are not in use but they are not for sale. How do I find potential sellers?

Answer (score 1):

Patents are owned by the assignees. If you want to purchase or license a patent you will have to contact the assignee directly.  There is no guarantee they will be willing to sell or license. I know of no secondary markets for patents.